# Looking For Data Structure To Add Numbers Consecutively

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Like the title says I'm trying to add numbers consecutively. Here's an example:

[image]

I'm preatty sure there's a data structure for this but don't remember what it's called. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about a [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Are you trying to sum up the numbers from 1 to N, inclusive? Or are you trying to add up subranges?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to add all the numbers inclusively.

Comment: n(n+1)/2 is the formula for this sum

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure math, which is a better fit at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more of a math question than a data structures question. :-)

The sum of the numbers 1 + 2 + ... + n is equal to n(n + 1) / 2. This number is called the nth [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was told their was a data structure for this but I guess this works too. Thanks again for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Data-Structure for this simple summing problem is a overkill. If the number is consecutive, then `n(n + 1) / 2` is the best formula for drive this. Even if the consecutive sequence start from any random number like `[8 9 10 11 12 13]`, then you can still calculate it by `((13 * (13 + 1)) / 2) - ((7 * (7 + 1)) / 2)`.

Further if you need data-structure, then you can use [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to calculate Range Sum uery. (It is best suit when the data is not consecutive)